# I need to read a text file from a javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing webpage with a javascript to read data files in text format from the server per user request. Once the text file has been loaded, I need to manipulate the data somewhat.

I have been using XMLHttpRequest for the loading, however, now I see that synchronous requests are "deprecated". I can't start manipulating the data before it's loaded, so what can I do in this case?

Comment: Not use Synchronous but Asynchronous requests. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use an [*a*synchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) (or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), see below, which is also asynchronous):

```
function doGET(path, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // The request is done; did it work?
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // ***Yes, use `xhr.responseText` here***
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                // ***No, tell the callback the call failed***
                callback(null);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", path);
    xhr.send();
}

function handleFileData(fileData) {
    if (!fileData) {
        // Show error
        return;
    }
    // Use the file data
}

// Do the request
doGET("/path/to/file", handleFileData);
```

<s>Or using promises, which are the more modern way to handle callbacks (but keep reading):</s>

```
function doGET(path, callback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                // The request is done; did it work?
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    // Yes, use `xhr.responseText` to resolve the promise
                    resolve(xhr.responseText);
                } else {
                    // No, reject the promise
                    reject(xhr);
                }
             }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", path);
        xhr.send();
    });
}

// Do the request
doGET("/path/to/file")
    .then(function(fileData) {
        // Use the file data
    })
    .catch(function(xhr) {
        // The call failed, look at `xhr` for details
    });
```

Here in 2019, there's no reason to use XHR wrapped in a promise like that, just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

```
function doGET(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status); // Rejects the promise
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. I've tried using "return" to return the value from this function, but it always returns "undefined", because it isn't loaded yet. I've also tried setting a global variable equal to the result, but it is set to "undefined", because it isn't loaded yet. Should I put my entire application inside this function?

Comment: My point is, it doesn't make any sense for the script to continue, until the result is in. I feel it is absolutely counter-intuitive that the synchronous call is now deprecated.

Comment: @OZ1SEJ: Synchronous calls require blocking the JavaScript thread the call runs on. If that's the main UI thread (the default one), nothing else can happen on the page until the call completes. That locks up the UI of the page (at least) or the browser (in some cases). Asynchronous requests allow the page to remain responsive while the network operation is in progress. If you want to work with JavaScript on the browser, you need to embrace asynchronous operations.

Comment: I do see the point now. I just had to get my around this. I took an hour's break to clean my bathroom, and then it hit me ;-) Thanks!

Comment: These days most requests will likely be blocked. I used to be able to read in my pastebins, but now getting this error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pastebin.com/raw/<pastebin_hash>' from origin 'https://www.somesite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: @thdoan - There's no reason to think the above will be blocked. It just sounds like pastebin moved something and now the code you're running is on a different origin from the thing you're trying to load. That's the Same Origin Policy. It isn't new.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I used to grab text from pastebins from different domains, so I know that used to be possible. Now that they have their own [Scraping API](https://pastebin.com/doc_scraping_api), they are now actively blocking IPs that are scraping since they want to push people to use their Scraping API (a paid service).

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to handle the local file, Try this

Make use of [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
function readFile(file)
{
    var f = new XMLHttpRequest();
    f.open("GET", file, false);
    f.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(f.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(f.status === 200 || f.status == 0)
            {
                var res= f.responseText;
                alert(res);
            }
        }
    }
    f.send(null);
}
```

Then you have to call with `File:\\`

```
readFile('File:\\\yourpath');
```

Comment: Yes, I can alert the result *inside* the function, but either I need to get the result *out* of the function somehow, or I need to put my entire application inside that innermost if-statement...?

Comment: @OZ1SEJ: Just put your code that handles the file data in a function that accepts an argument, and have the asynchronous code call that function when the data is ready. I've updated the CW answer to show doing that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So, basically, I should call my entire application from within this function? Also, what do you mean by "CW answer"?

Comment: @OZ1SEJ: You should have that function be the starting point of processing the file. It can (and should) call other functions, of course. "CW" means "community wiki," I was referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40201172/157247).